# Create subjects automatically from Schema Registry - Subject not found

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I have Schema Registry container `http://registry-server:8081`

**ProducerConfig**:

```
     bootstrap.servers : [PLAINTEXT://kafka-server:9092]
     value.serializer : class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

and a `Standalone service` that acts as a producer and has its property set as below

**Producer**

```
   "schema.registry.url", "http://registry-server:8081"
   "bootstrap.servers", "http://kafka-server:9092
   "value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy", true
   "auto.register.schemas", false
   "value.serializer", DelegatingSerialzer.class
```

**KafkaAvroSerializerConfig**

```
    value.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy
    key.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy
```

But when the `Standalone service` attempt to send a request to schema registry, something like below

```
   http://registry-server:8081/subjects/topicName-value?deleted=false
```

I constantly receive **Subject Not Found error**.

Is it because `auto.register.schemas` is set to `false` in the Producer from standalone service and that's why it is failing to create subjects ?

How can I auto register schema and auto create Subject from the Schema Registry service ?

btw, kafka, schema-registery and standalone-app are containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it because auto.register.schemas is set to false in the Producer from standalone service and that's why it is failing to create subjects ?

Probably

> auto register schema and auto create Subject from the Schema Registry service ?

You can't. The registry needs to have *external* POST HTTP requests sent to it to create schemas for subjects. You cannot create subject without any schema.

The registry itself doesn't start with any schema, usually only your client applications do, so there is nothing it can (auto) register itself.